# In a Cocoa Application for macOS, is it possible to get notified during a selection change and not only at the end of the change?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I would like to track the selection of a NSTextView continuously, but I only succeed to get the change when the selection finishes changing using :

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)notification {

}
```

Is there a way to track selection changes continuously ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to solve the issue by subclassing NSTextView and overriding the following method:

```
-(void)setSelectedRanges:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)selectedRanges affinity:(NSSelectionAffinity)affinity stillSelecting:(BOOL)stillSelecting {

    [super setSelectedRanges:selectedRanges affinity:affinity stillSelecting:stillSelecting];

    if (stillSelecting && [self delegate] && [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(textViewDidChangeSelection:)]) {
        NSNotification *note = [[NSNotification alloc] initWithName:@"TextViewSelectionIsChangingNotification" object:self userInfo:nil];
        [[self delegate] textViewDidChangeSelection:note];
    }

}
```

This seems to me a good solution, it works well. Thanks.